# How to paste values into a row, but the row number is dynamic?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to paste values into a row, however the row number will change each week with the length of the dataset. The row to paste into will be the row containing "PolandUNKNOWN" in column A.

**Non-dynamic code works**

```vb
Sub Paste_Balancing_Items_Non_Dynamic()

Dim BB As Worksheet
Dim BL As Worksheet

Set BB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BALANCING BACKLOG")
Set BL = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BACKLOG - CURRENT WEEK")

BB.Range("E48:L48").Copy
BL.Range("X881:AE881").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
BB.Range("M48:T48").Copy
BL.Range("AF881:AM881").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

**For the dynamic code, I have**

```vb
Sub Paste_Balancing_Items_Dynamic_V2()

Dim BB As Worksheet
Dim BL As Worksheet
Dim count, i As Long

Set BB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BALANCING BACKLOG")
Set BL = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BACKLOG - CURRENT WEEK (01.06)")

count = BL.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
MsgBox count
i = 3

BB.Range("E48:L48").Copy

Do While i <= count

    If Cells(i, 1).Value = "PolandUNKNOWN" Then ' <-- error here
        BL.Range(Cells(i, 5)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End If

    i = i + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

I am getting

> Runtime error '13': Type mismatch

on the line indicated above

Do I even need the loop?

Comment: In your error line, `Cells` is unqualified. You need to ensure it points to the correct worksheet. So unless it is pointing to the proper worksheet (eg `BL.Cells`), it will fail.  However, to find the last instance of a string in a column, I would suggest the `Range.Find`. Be sure to set **all** the parameters as they carry over from the last used instance, and use `searchDirection:=xlprevious`

Comment: As @RonRosenfeld suggests - use [FIND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) . Another link to a good resource - [FIND](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-find/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's only one value to find then `Match` would be faster:

```vb
Sub Paste_Balancing_Items_Dynamic_V2()

    Dim BB As Worksheet
    Dim BL As Worksheet
    Dim m
    
    Set BB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BALANCING BACKLOG")
    Set BL = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BACKLOG - CURRENT WEEK (01.06)")
    
    m = Application.Match("PolandUNKNOWN", BL.Columns("A"), 0)
    'if m is not an error means we got a match
    If Not IsError(m) Then
        CopyValues BB.Range("E48:L48"), BL.Cells(m, 5)
    End If

End Sub

'utility method to replace copy/paste values
Sub CopyValues(rngFrom As Range, rngTo As Range)
    With rngFrom
        rngTo.Cells(1).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much it works perfectly :D Saves me a lot of time headscratching!