# Getting error 'Compile Error: Sub or Function not defined' when trying to use CopyValues

Tags: vba

new VBA user here.

I am getting the error `Compile Error: Sub or Function not defined` on the code below -

```
Sub Paste_Backlog_Balancing_Items()

    Dim BB As Worksheet
    Dim BL As Worksheet
    Dim p
    
    Set BB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BALANCING BACKLOG")
    Set BL = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BACKLOG - CURRENT WEEK")
    
    p = Application.Match("NordicsUNKNOWN", BL.Columns("A"), 0)
 
    If Not IsError(p) Then
        CopyValues BB.Range("E48:L48"), BL.Cells(p, 24)
        CopyValues BB.Range("M48:T48"), BL.Cells(p, 32)
        
    End If
End Sub
```

Please can someone explain this error, the advice on Microsoft is not very helpful>

To correct this error:

Make sure that the procedure name is spelled correctly.

Find the name of the project containing the procedure you want to call in the References dialog box. If it does not appear, click the Browse button to search for it. Select the check box to the left of the project name, and then click OK.

Check the name of the routine.

Many thanks

Comment: Where is `CopyValues` sub/function defined?

Comment: Thanks, why do I need to define CopyValues?

Comment: Is it something like this? Public Function toto(val As Integer) As Integer
    toto = val * 2
End Function

Comment: Because else the VBA runtime does not know what you want to do. There is no build in routine with the name, so it looks for a user defined routine with that name. If it doesn't exists, you get that error.

Comment: You're missing the `CopyValues` procedure from my answer to your previous post... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67820372/trying-to-paste-values-into-a-row-but-the-row-number-is-dynamic-row-number-is   If you want to use it then it has to be included...

Comment: Thanks all. @TimWilliams, which is the CopyValues procedure in your solution pls? I can't for the life of me see the difference!

Answer (score 0):

You're using calls to a procedure `CopyValues` which does not appear in your posted code.  Do you have a procedure with that name in your VBA project?

If it's the same one posted in an answer to your previous question then you need to add this code:

```vb
'utility method to replace copy/paste values
Sub CopyValues(rngFrom As Range, rngTo As Range)
    With rngFrom
        rngTo.Cells(1).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

[Trying to paste values into a row, but the row number is dynamic, row number is the row containing specific text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67820372/trying-to-paste-values-into-a-row-but-the-row-number-is-dynamic-row-number-is)

If that's not the issue, then please provide more detail on exactly what is highlighted when the error occurs.